# Destructive Interference of two wave pulses

Tags: waves, energy-conservation, interference, superposition

Suppose two identical  transverse wave pulses are travelling towards each other on a string where one is inverted with respect to the other. When they meet, destructive interference will occur and the string will be straight for a certain instant of time. Hence, for that instant, it will appear to have no energy. What then happens to the energy carried by the two pulses?

Comment: Or is it the reverse, the kinetic energy is gone and it's all stored as potential energy in the tension of the string?

Answer (score 1):

Similar situation to water waves.  In the 1700 Huygens also lined up a bunch of billiard balls in contact and struck both ends at the same time (like croquette[sp?]) and the balls at either end both move.

My guess is the energy is stored in the elasticity of the material.